# Java script game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for some help with my java script game as i have just started getting into it now,

my problem is that my animation loops infinitely on autopay and reloads the page every time it meets the condition to restart,
what I want to achieve is have a start button that would start the game and the animation and score on click  and if the condition for restart is met I have to press the start button again to play again

I would appreciate all the help I could get

```js
 const skate = document.getElementById("skate");
    const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
    const score = document.getElementById("score");

    function jump() {
    skate.classList.add("jump-animation");
    setTimeout(() =>
    skate.classList.remove("jump-animation"), 500);
    }

    document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (!skate.classList.contains('jump-animation')) {
    jump();
    }
    })

    setInterval(() => {
    const skateTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(skate)
    .getPropertyValue('top'));
     const rockLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(rock)
    .getPropertyValue('left'));
     score.innerText++;

     if (rockLeft < 0) {
     rock.style.display = 'none';
     } else {
     rock.style.display = ''
     }

     if (rockLeft < 50 && rockLeft > 0 && skateTop > 150) {
    
    location.reload();
    
    }
    }, 50);
```

```css
    #score { text-align: center; }

    #game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("./background.gif");
    background-size: cover;
    }

    #skate {
     height: 75px;
     width: 75px;
     top: 220px;
     position: relative;
     background-image: url("./skateboard.png");
     background-size: cover;
     }

     #rock {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     position: relative;
     top: 175px;
     left: 550px;
     background-image: url("./rock.png");
     background-size: cover;
     animation: rock 1.33s infinite;
     }

     @keyframes rock {
     0%{left: 550px;}
     100%{left: -50px;}
     }

     .jump-animation {
     animation: jump 0.5s;
     }

    @keyframes jump {
    0%{top: 225px;}
    50%{top: 75px;}
    75%{top: 75px;}
    100%{top: 225px;}
    }
```

```html
<div id="game">
    <div id="skate"></div>
    <div id="rock"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="score">0</h1>
```

Comment: don't call `location.reload()`

Comment: i have removed this but the animation still continues looping and the score counter is still increasing

Comment: Can you explain a game little bit

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to have a variable at the top scope of this module to track the ID of the current animation so that the animation/interval can be turned off if the user presses the start button before the current game ends. It should also turn off once the end-game condition is met, although I'm not really sure why window.getComputedStyle() is being used to compute the variables used for that condition, but I guess it's still a work in progress.

EDIT: Somehow I didn't notice that the player and obstacle were already in the game so I added colors to them for easier debugging, at least on my end. This time I made it so that the rock will lose then immediately regain a class for its animation, but the re-addition needs to be asynchronous even if the delay is 0ms.

index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="skate"></div>
        <div id="rock"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="score">0</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="new-game">New Game </button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    const skate = document.getElementById("skate");
    const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
    const score = document.getElementById("score");
    const newGameButton = document.getElementById("new-game");

    function jump() {
        skate.classList.add("jump-animation");
        setTimeout(() => skate.classList.remove("jump-animation"), 500);
    }

    document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        if (!skate.classList.contains('jump-animation')) {
            jump();
        }
    });


    let animationId;
    newGameButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        resetScore();
        resetRockAnimation();
        playScoreAnimation();


        function resetScore() {
            clearInterval(animationId);
            score.innerText = 0;
        }
        function resetRockAnimation() {
            rock.classList = [];
            setTimeout(() => rock.classList.add('rock-animation'), 0);
        }
        function playScoreAnimation() {
            animationId = setInterval(() => {
                const skateTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(skate).getPropertyValue('top'));
                const rockLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(rock).getPropertyValue('left'));
                score.innerText++;

                if (rockLeft < 0) {
                    rock.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    rock.style.display = '';
                }

                if (rockLeft < 50 && rockLeft > 0 && skateTop > 150) {
                    clearInterval(animationId);
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    });
</script>
```

style.css

```
#score {
    text-align: center;
}

#game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("./background.gif");
    background-size: cover;
}

#skate {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    top: 225px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("./skateboard.png");
    background-size: cover;

    background-color: slategrey;
}

#rock {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 175px;
    left: 550px;
    background-image: url("./rock.png");
    background-size: cover;

    background-color: lightcoral ;
}

.rock-animation {
    animation: rock 1.33s infinite;
}

@keyframes rock {
    0% {
        left: 550px;
    }

    100% {
        left: -50px;
    }
}

.jump-animation {
    animation: jump 0.5s;
}

@keyframes jump {
    0% {
        top: 225px;
    }

    50% {
        top: 75px;
    }

    75% {
        top: 75px;
    }

    100% {
        top: 225px;
    }
}
```

Comment: the animation for #rock is still looping without the press of the button hen i have added these changes. the jump function and the score do not activate until i press new game as it should thouigh

Comment: I guess I got confused because I couldn't see the skate or rock elements and just assumed you were still working on that, so I only focused on the score

Comment: I don't know if people get notified when an answer is updated, but this comment is to let you know that I did